# Media Features, not work?

Tags: css

I have little problem :

I make version of site to Iphone 5

but this code:

```
@media screen and (max-devise-width:568px) and (device-aspect-ratio:  2730/1000) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
}
```

does not work, while this code:

```
@media screen and (max-devise-width:568px)
```

works, but I want to add also `device-aspect-ratio` and `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`

Comment: max-`devise`-width : is it a typo?

Comment: yes, sorry max-width:568px

Comment: Did you try `(device-aspect-ratio:  2730/1000)` on its own to see if it is matching anything?

Answer (score 1):

You have `max-devise-width` spelled with an `s` - it should be `device`.

(If that's an error re-typing your code into StackOverflow, please **don't do that**!  Always copy-and-paste your real code.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've normally seen that written when targeting an iPhone5:

```
@media screen and (max-width:560px) and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```